Flutter Error Building iOS App in Simulator After Updating macOS, Xcode, and iOS
I encountered an issue when trying to run a Flutter app on the iPhone Simulator using the flutter run command after updating my development environment. The build failed with errors related to module caching and missing files in Xcode.
This issue occurs across all projects, including newly created ones and existing projects, indicating that it might not be specific to any particular project configuration.
Here are the updates made before the issue occurred:
macOS: Updated to Sequoia 15.2
Xcode: Updated to version 16
iOS: Simulator running iOS version 18
Flutter Run Error Photo Example on VSCode : (https://i.sstatic.net/2fTyFxhM.jpg)
Example of Error Photos in Xcode :(https://i.sstatic.net/KPcKUKUG.jpg)
I expected the app to build successfully and launch on the simulator without errors, as it did before updating macOS, Xcode, and iOS.
